# Continuously populating a tableview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView that I want updated by a method called by a timer. What I have now is:

```
-(void) populateTable {
NSLog(@"done");
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ob 1",@"ob 2",@"ob 3",nil];
self.listData = array;
[array release];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(populateTable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.listData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
return cell;

 }
```

If i put the array and `self.listData = array` into `viewDidLoad` it works, but won't repeat. My method `populateTable` is being called, but doesn't actually put anything in the table. This is my first time using a UITableView so I don't know too much how they work. I did this much by following a tutorial. How can use a method to populate the data?

Comment: Hey -- on this older question, for googlers here's a pointer to a modern approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/25604378/294884 hope it helps someone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also call `reloadData` on your table.

Comment: For posterity: `[[self tableView] reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your timer to a run loop - right now you create the NSTimer object, but since it never makes it into a run loop, it fires once and stops. Try something like this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(populateTable)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inform you view about a new entry in the array.

Something like

`[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

In this case indexArray is a array of IndexPaths which gives the information where you updated the array.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
NSArray *indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
```

Afterwards the view will call you tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: methode the get the object.

btw. IHMO it is better you model is a  `NSMutableArray` where you can add something.
In your implementation of `populateTable` you just replace always you array .

PS: call a reloadData only

> ... when you assign a new data source. Reloading the table view clears current state, including the current selection ... (UITableView Class Reference)